# How to make text button autosize to fit button

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, kotlin, android-button

How can I make the button text auto adjust its size to fit the button?

I've tried to set:

```
android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
```

but that doesn't work.
And the text still ends up in two lines if I put:

```
android:maxLines="1"
```

with some part of the text gone.

Is there any way, programmatically or in XML, to autosize the text to fit the button on one line and that also shows the whole text?

**Edit :**

Here is my XML, the button I want to fit the text in is "btnReq" and "btnAcc":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".PlayFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tableLayout"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.074"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingRight="10dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_email"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="email"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnReq"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="REQUEST"
                android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
                android:maxLines="1"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnAcc"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="ACCEPT"
                android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
                android:maxLines="1"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="false"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn9"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Please show the full xml code for this button...

Comment: @deHaar added the xml just now

Comment: That's kind of tricky because due to using the layout weight (with `android:layout_width="0dp"` and `android:layout_weight="1"`), the button's width doesn't (only) depend on the text width anymore...

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview), the `autoSizeTextType` property works on **TextView** only.

Change your button to TextView:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/btnAcc"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="ACCEPT"
    android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
    android:maxLines="1"/>
```

And then define the `onClick` method on it:

```
android:onClick="onButtonClick"
```

to make it work like a button.

Also, please keep in mind that the `autoSizeTextType` property is available starting from 
 **Android 8.0 (API level 26)**

Comment: It is not correct. The `MaterialButton` and then the `AppCompatButton` have a `TextView` inside. You can use `autoSizeTextType` also with them.

Comment: Also, it is available on lower API levels using AppCompatTextView.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti actually a `Button` has always been a `TextView`, so it doesn't have a `TextView` inside it, it is a `TextView` ;-)

Answer (score 1):

you can use a RelaytiveLayout and textview instead of button. and create a drawable shadow design for your Relative layout then it look likes a button. and you can give a width to your relative layout and give a mach parent to your text.